# FormsAuthenticationTicket: how to keep the user logged in after the browser has been closed?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm logging the user this way, using `FormsAuthenticationTicket`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginView)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(loginView.Email, loginView.Password))
        {
            var user = (CustomMembershipUser)Membership.GetUser(loginView.Email, false);
            if (user != null)
            {
                CustomPrincipalSerializeModel userSerializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel()
                {
                    ID = user.ID,
                    FirstName = user.FirstName,
                    LastName = user.LastName,
                    RoleName = user.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleName).ToList()
                };

                string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userSerializeModel);
                DateTime expirationDate = loginView.KeepMeLoggedIn ? DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12) : DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.UserName, DateTime.Now, expirationDate, false, userData);

                HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie("CookieFA", FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
                Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Error");

    return View("Login");
}
```

But even if I set `loginView.KeepMeLoggedIn` to `true` (which should keep the login for 1 year), when I close the browser and I reopen the website, the user is logged off.

How can I keep it logged in also when I close the browser?

Comment: Works for me. Are you still being logged of if you login and close the browser and reopen with 15 minutes (when `KeepMeLoggedIn` is `false`)

Comment: I would add a code like this: `if (authTicket.IsPersistent) { faCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: yes! If I set each KeepMeLoggedIn true or false nothing change. Every time I close the browser, once I reopen it (immediately) it is logged off :(

Comment: @SimonMourier: where? Before `Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);`?

Comment: yes for example

Comment: @SimonMourier: tried, nothing change! I've the same problem. I've noticed this: if I open Chrome and I look at the CookieFA, it writes unders `Expires / Max-Age` the value `1969-12-31T23:59:59`. It doesn't make sense :O

Comment: The 5th parameter to FormsAuthenticationTicket should also be true

Comment: Ohhh nice! Using the 5° param true and the Simon Mourier tips, it works :) Place the answer, and you will get my bounty :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set the 5th parameter of the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` constructor '`isPersistent`' to true.

Then I would add change the code to this:

```
var faCookie = new HttpCookie("CookieFA", FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
if (authTicket.IsPersistent)
{
    faCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
}
Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
```

And if you also want to honor what's configured in web.config, you can add this extra code (optional):

```
var faCookie= new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
faCookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;

if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL)
{
    faCookie.Secure = true;
}

if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
{
    faCookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
}
...
```